# A hierarchy of dictionary items in Razor syntax

Tags: c#, dictionary, razor, umbraco

Is it possible to use the hierarchy of dictionary items in the Razor Syntax?

What I want to be able to do is set up Dictionary Terms on a Page/Widget basis. An example of the dictionary and Razor is below:

```
Documents
    DocumentPlaceholder

@Umbraco.Field("Documents.DocumentPlaceholder");
```

Is this possible to do? If not, I guess I'll have to create the Dictionary Terms in the way below instead:

```
Documents
    Documents.DocumentPlaceholder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it isn't possible, I'm afraid. Have been bitten by this in the past, so I have a habit of always naming my dictionary terms "[Area]Term", so in your case "[Documents]DocumentPlaceholder". Don't know why I went with [] and not . like you suggest :-s

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information! I'll use the latter solution for Dictionary Terms now.